# code that will be true only if 1 out of 3 or 3 out of three are true

Tags: python, boolean

Should you do if statements to sum up numbers and only make number 1 and 3 true or is there another way?

```
g= bool(a) != bool(b) != bool(c)
```

Comment: This question is unclear.  I suggest title "_Python: true if one or three among three are true_".  Also, clarify "if" is Python code, wrap in code backticks so it appears as `if`.  Lastly, your sentence mentions "sum up numbers" but the title is "be true".  It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `xor` operator: `bool(a) ^ bool(b) ^ bool(c)`:

```
for a in [True, False]:
    for b in [True, False]:
        for c in [True, False]:
            print(a, b, c, ":", a ^ b ^ c)
```

output:

```
True True True : True
True True False : False
True False True : False
True False False : True
False True True : False
False True False : True
False False True : True
False False False : False
```

Comment: but the problem I have is that when the input is 3 false variables I get a false when it should be a true

Comment: This comment conflicts with your problem description. You have zero `True` items and zero is not an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sum` here:

```
sum(a, b, c) in {0, 1, 3}
```

As an example function:

```
def check(*args):
    return sum(args) in {0, 1, len(args)}

for a in [True, False]:
    for b in [True, False]:
        for c in [True, False]:
            print(a, b, c, ":", check(a, b, c))
```

Which prints:

```
True True True : True
True True False : False
True False True : False
True False False : True
False True True : False
False True False : True
False False True : True
False False False : True
```

If you need to ensure the args are treated as truthy values then just use the handy dandy map function:

```
return sum(map(bool, args)) in {0, 1, len(args)}
```

Comment: I added `0` to the condition set as I saw your comment otherwise just use `{1, len(args)}`

Answer (score 0):

Booleans in python can be cast to integers, and ints to booleans so you can do something like

```
finalVar = bool((int(var1)+int(var2)+int(var3)) % 2)
```

To Add to this from the latest comment: "if all 3 are false it should be true", you can use a Ternary Operator to get the edge case of all being 0:

```
temp = bool(int(var1)+int(var2)+int(var3))
finalVar = True if temp == 0 else temp % 2
```

Comment: but the problem I have is that when the input is 3 false variables I get a false when it should be a true

Comment: @AlejandroDeliusSciaroni Your comment conflicts with your problem description. You have ````zero```` True items and zero is not an odd number.